# AWGN for a specific dBc

Tags: noise, gaussian

I have a square-ware signal with 1V peak-to-peak (alternating between -500 and +500mV, so its absolute value is a constant 500mV) and I would like to add to this an AWGN expressed in dBc ("decibels relative to the carrier").

**How I should generate such normal distribution noise?**

I got a hint that - for e.g. -40dBc - the following code would work:

```
normal(0, (m.pow(10, (-40 / 20)) / 2), ..)
```

However this ends up generating a lower dBc value (around -31 dBc), meaning "stronger" noise than expected.

Reading around made me find the description of "half-normal distribution", which states that the expected absolute value scales not with sigma, but with sigma*sqrt(2/pi). I tried the following code - and it does seem to work - but I would like to ask for your kind input on whether my thinking was correct and if this code is the appropriate one:

```
normal(0, (m.pow(10, (-40 / 20)) / 2 / m.sqrt(2 / m.pi)), ..)
```

The way I calculated effective dBc was this:

- Integrate carrier (in this case it is t*0.5 [V] <- let us call this a
- Integrate the output of normal() <- let us call this b
- Calculate 20 * log10(b / a)

Notes:

- The code sniplets above are Python-like
- The "/ 2" is there as my carrier is 1V peak-to-peak

Comment: so, can you, mathematically, what the power of the square wave you're describing is? Because your dBc values are "**power** relative to the carrier power", and I feel like your question would be a lot easier to answer by yourself if you understood that – but I might simply be mistaken, which is why I'm asking.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and your answer Marcus.
Right, and I assume a constant impedance.

Comment: so, what *is* the power of your square wave?

Comment: sorry, I phrased myself vaguely. I meant that I have a constant resistive R and the signal generator is an ideal voltage source, so the power of the carrier will just be P = V*V/R, where V is the modulated carrier

Comment: exactly, so your square wave "carrier" has a power of 0.5²/R. Let's arbitrarily set R=1, so then we end up with a power of ¼ for your carrier. Was this known to you? Great! So, what's the power of zero-mean noise with variance $\sigma^2$?

Comment: if we continue being unit-less, take R=1 and discard t, it should be (1 / sigma ** 2)
if this is true, the power in decibels relative to the carrier would be 10*log10(0.25 / (1 / sigma ** 2)), meaning 20*log10(sigma / 2)
if this is true, it means that to get a specific dBc value x, sigma := 2*10^(x / 20), e.g. for -40dBc, sigma := 0.02

Comment: we don't discard $t$ – this is *digital* signal processing, so everything is inherently "per sample", which is unitless, anyway, and thus there's no $t$ to begin with! No, the noise power is **not** $\frac1{\sigma^2}$, it's simply $\sigma^2$! And "meaning ... " makes no sense. please be a bit more careful with wording!

Comment: (tried to move this to chat, as the forum suggested, but to no avail)

right, my mistake: it is indeed sigma^2, thus sigma for a specific dBc value x is (10^(x/20))/2, correct? for -40dBc sigma = 0.005

the newlines do not seem to appear as intended (this time i insert double newlines -> hope this works)